# Search Apostrophe using Fulltext Thesaurus search

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I'm trying to implement the fulltext search on one of our tables, and everything is running smoothly except when it comes to the word international.

in the table, the forms of the word that show up are `intl`, `int'l` and `international` and as such I made the thesaurus file reflect that:

```
<expansion>
    <sub>intl</sub>
    <sub>int'l</sub>
    <sub>international</sub>
</expansion>
```

However, when attempting this search, it will only match intl and international with int'l requiring an exact search.  Is there any way that I can include the apostrophe into the search?

The portion of the query that is relevant is something like this (not exactly that but similar):

```
SELECT * FROM CustomerTable Where contains((CustomerName), 'FORMSOF(Thesaurus, "int''l")')
```

I decided to see what words it was parsing using

```
SELECT display_term as term FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('FORMSOF(Thesaurus, "int''l")', 0, null, 0)
```

and the results showed me that it is splitting **`int`** and **`l`**

```
+---------------+
|     term      |
+---------------+
| int           |
| l             |
| intl          |
| international |
+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the word breaker for the Neutral language doesn't allow apostrophes in words. You could switch the language of the full text index to English (and re-index), or create your own custom [word-breaker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142509.aspx) to allow apostrophes.

The internet seems to be lacking in examples of custom word breakers but you can start by looking at Windows Search SDK on which SQL full text is built on:

[Windows Search Developer's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872109%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

[Windows Search: Extending the Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb318649%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Hmm thanks for the help, this is really confusing as the only instructions I can find tells me to create a custom dictionary which won't be possible since we can't know what abbreviations they use. :/

Comment: "The problem is the default word breaker doesn't allow apostrophes in words. " Do you have any source for that ? I cant find it in the links you provided. I am having a similar issue where I can't search using a wildcard * with an apostrophe

Comment: My original answer wasn't clear on Neutral vs. English language. I have updated it.